# dired: different action from same bind based on file type (extension), maybe hydra?

Tags: dired

i really would love to have the option to launch different apps for a specific file type. for example if i have a `.jpeg` file i would want an option to launch in gimp, inkscape etc.
Ideally i would love to have a keybind that launches a menu (maybe using hydra?) that will present the launch options. if this could be dynamic based on a file type (extension maybe?) that would be amazing, but i'll also be glad with maybe just a general menu with all available actions.
any ideas?

Comment: `(require 'dired-x)` and just use `!` ? See `dired-read-shell-command`. There are often numerous guesses which you can cycle through, if the first wasn't what you wanted; and of course it can be configured.

Comment: thx. yeah i know about ! but prefer a menu for quick launching stuff i pre define :)

Comment: Fair enough (although I do think `! RET` to execute your pre-defined favourite is pretty darn quick). FWIW I'd be inclined personally to base any menu generation off the same data, for the sake of consistency with the existing interface. You can define options in `dired-guess-shell-alist-user`. If you indicate what kind of "menu" you're after, it would probably help someone to make a suggestion? I'm guessing you're after some kind of pop-up menu? What do you already use that generates something similar?

Comment: yeah a pop-up menu would be great. i usually use hydras for such things. i have zero coding skills but use hydras to quick launch commands/functions which is pretty easy. thx!