# Dired: File open using external viewers, based on filetype, and without prompting

Tags: dired, files, linux, openwith

When I hit `RETURN` on a filename in Dired, I'd like Emacs to automatically do one of several things, depending on the file's type:

1 - **If it's a text file**, I'd like to open the file in a new buffer in Emacs.

2 - **If the filetype is listed in a user-configurable list of filetypes and external viewers**, open the file in an external viewer associated with that filetype.

3 - **If the filetype is not text and not in the above list**, return an error saying the file is of an unknown type.

I've found some answers ([1](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/42542/dired-open-files-by-external-application-in-linux), [2](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/23855/dired-different-action-from-same-bind-based-on-file-type-extension-maybe-hyd)) that advise using `dired-read-shell-command` and either `!` or `&` to open files with external viewers.

The above answers are insufficient for my needs, because:

1 - They **require multiple keystrokes** (at least `!` or `&` and then `RETURN` at the prompt), while I want this done with just a single keystroke, without any prompting.

2 - They **won't open text files in Emacs**, but will instead try to use external viewers for everything.  I want text files opened in Emacs.

3 - They **dispatch based on filename extensions**, while I want to dispatch based on filetype (*ie. as a result of using either the "`file`" or "`mimetype`" command on linux*)

4 - They **don't error-out if the filetype is not found** in the list of known filetypes.

Comment: Maybe this could help you.. https://github.com/Fuco1/dired-hacks#dired-open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a macOS specific solution as it needs `file(1)` and `open(1)`. Feel free to adjust the code.

```el
(defun chunyang-file-mime-type (file)
  "Return mime-type of FILE."
  ;; file(1) doesn't fail in such case
  (unless (file-readable-p file)
    (error "%s: No such file or no read permission" file))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (let ((exit (call-process "file" nil t nil "--brief" "--mime-type" file)))
      ;; Remove the final newline if any
      (when (eq (char-before) ?\n)
        (delete-char -1))
      (if (zerop exit)
          (buffer-string)
        (error "file: %s: %s" file (buffer-string))))))

(defun chunyang-open-file-with-app (file app)
  "Open FILE with APP."
  ;; open(1) exists immediately and does not block Emacs
  (call-process "open" nil nil nil "-a" app file))

(defvar chunyang-mime-type-app-alist
  '(("video/mp4" . "VLC")
    ("application/pdf" . "Firefox")))

(defun chunyang-open-file (file)
  "Open FILE base on its mime-type."
  (interactive "f")
  (setq file (expand-file-name file))
  (let ((mime-type (chunyang-file-mime-type file)))
    (if (string-prefix-p "text/" mime-type)
        (find-file file)
      (let ((app (cdr (assoc mime-type chunyang-mime-type-app-alist))))
        (if app
            (chunyang-open-file-with-app file app)
          (user-error "No app is associated with %s" mime-type))))))

(defun chunyang-dired-open-file ()
  (interactive)
  (chunyang-open-file (dired-get-file-for-visit)))
```